# google maps addListener not working properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have a separate code for google maps v3. Just for show infowindow infobox in my google fusion kml layer when i click on it. Yesterday my code is work fine. i didn't make any change. but today my addListner not working. when i copy my back up project, same as code. it work again but tomorrow that happens again. My addListener not work.

here's my code

```
infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
  map: map,
  shadowStyle: 1,
  padding: 5,
  borderRadius: 4,
  arrowSize: 20,
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: '#2c2c2c',
  disableAutoPan: true,
  hideCloseButton: false,
  backgroundClassName: 'phoney',
  arrowStyle: 2,
});

function get_details(mode,id,lati,lng)
  {
     $('#loading').show();
        if (xhr != null)
        {
           xhr.abort();
        }
        xhr = $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
            url: "realisasi2.php?id="+id,
           data: "m="+mode+"&id="+id,
           success: function(ret){
                ajaxres = JSON.parse(ret);
                iconpos = new google.maps.LatLng(lati,lng);
                psbchurndata = ajaxres.detail;
                var html = psbchurndata+"<i><a class='ajax' href='#' onclick=layer22("+id+","+lati+","+lng+") style='font-family: Arial;font-size: 12px; color:#00CC29;'>Lihat Datel </a></i>";
                infoBubble.setContent('<div class="infowindow"><br />'+html+'</div>');
                infoBubble.setPosition(iconpos);
                infoBubble.close();
                infoBubble.open(map);
                 $('#loading').hide();
           }
         });
  }


layer.setMap(map);   
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) { 

alert(JSON.stringify(e, null, 4)); //UNDIFINED not Working

  var lati = e.latLng['mb'];  
  var lng = e.latLng['nb'];  
  var x = e.row['id_witel'].value;
  get_details('w',e.row['id_witel'].value,lati,lng);    
});


}
```

thank's for any help

Comment: I have seen similar problems where sometimes the result of a click on an "old" fusion table layer is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no "official" properties `mb` and `nb` for a `google.maps.LatLng`(that's what `e.latLng` is) . These properties will be used internally by the API, the names of these properties may change the next moment, hour or day.

To retrieve latitude and longitude use the methods `lat()` and `lng()` of `e.latLng`